# При наведении на картинку появляется текст html

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как реализовать?
Пытался сделать по примеру https://it-media.kiev.ua/article/pri-navedenii-na-kartinku-poyavlyaetsya-tekst-ili-knopka-css-reshenie.html
но не получается, так как появляемый текст находится в другом блоке.

http://jsfiddle.net/yDwKa/

```
<style>
.first_block {
    display: inline-block;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px red solid;
    padding:10px;
}
.second_block {
    display: none;
}
.first_block:hover .second_block {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<div class='first_block'>

</div>
<div class='second_block'>
        Текст
    </div>
```

Не получается изменить этот пример так, чтобы текст появлялся за  первым блоком, а не внутри первого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться:

[смежным селектором](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)  (символ `+`) ищет элемент непосредственно за

[селектором следующего элемента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (символ `~`) находит второй элемент только если ему предшествует первый, и они оба имеют общего родителя

```css
.first_block {
    height:100px;
    border:1px red solid;
}
.second_block {
    display: none;
}
.first_block:hover + .second_block {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='first_block'></div>
<div class='second_block'>Текст</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как поступить в данном случае? http://jsfiddle.net/yDwKa/  Когда элемент не является следующим

Comment: @Евгений поступить в смысле сделать текст под блоком?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/412ogfkL/ Обновленная ссылка, появление текста в другом блоке, не последующем

Comment: @Евгений если только поменять верстку http://jsfiddle.net/0fg1z92k/ или же javascript

Comment: Спасибо! А как реализовать подобное через javascript?

Comment: @Евгений http://jsfiddle.net/ykfvdnhq/